# How can code this unique ascii art in java?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
+--------+
|   /\   |
|  /--\  |
| /====\ |
|<------>|
| \====/ |
|  \--/  |
|   \/   |
+--------+
```

How can I draw this ascii art in Java?

```
int size=4;
System.out.print("+");
for(int i=1;i<=size*2;i++){
    System.out.print("-");
}
System.out.print("+");
System.out.println();
for (int i=1;i<=2*size-1 ;i++) {
    System.out.print("|");
    System.out.println();


}
System.out.print("+");
for(int i=1;i<=size*2;i++){
    System.out.print("-");
}

System.out.print("+");
```

I have make this upon multiple sizes and for size=4 the above ascii art I will have to drawn. That's why I taken 4 as a int.

Till this code I made but after this I am not knowing how to make this completely?

Comment: What is currently printed? Looks like you have no equal signs or `<>`  & `\/` characters.

Comment: Currently half shape is printing with no any = or - sign.

Comment: @SahilSingh: doesn't my answer at least help you get in the right direction? Why did you re-post the question?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing the code, I'll try to describe how I'd approach the problem.

Basically I'd try to find any kind of regularity.

At first glance there's 5 kinds of lines:

1. starting line
2. triangle
3. center line
4. upside-down triangle
5. ending line.

#5 is the same as #1 and #4 is the same as #2, but in the opposite order. So once we've figured out how to do 1.-3., we should be mostly done.

The starting line is very simple: a `+`, then *n*2* `-` and another `+`

The triangle is a bit trickier.

- There are *n-1* lines in each triangle part, let's call the index of the line `m` (starting at 0)
- In each line `m` there is a `|` followed by *n-(1+m)* spaces
- Then a `/`
- Then *m* filler characters (either `-` or `=`). This can be 0 for the first line.

  - The choice of filler character seems to be alternating, but the sample doesn't quite show enough data to know for sure.
- Then a `\`
- Then the same number of spaces as before followed by a final `|`.

The center line is rather similar to the start/end line: a `+` and a `<`, followed by (n-1)*2 `-`, followed by a `>` and a `+`.

This description should be fairly straight-forward to translate into various nested loops.

Comment: Just FYI: The OP has [re-asked the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66166314/522444).